# CefSharp check if its initialized

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm pretty new to C# but Chromium is loading a webpage, but I want to execute javascript if the chromium is initialized.

I didn't find any tutorial or explanation about `IsBrowserInitializedChanged` and don't know how to use it.

I would be very happy if someone can help me.

```
 private void InitChrome()
 {
     CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
     Cef.Initialize(settings);

 }


public Main(String username, String password)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitChrome();
    un = username;
    pw = password;

    chrome = new 
ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.thesite.com/#/auth/login");
    pPanel.Controls.Add(chrome);
    chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    chrome.ExecuteScriptAsync(File.ReadAllText(@"content\jquery-3.3.1.min.js"));
    chrome.ExecuteScriptAsync(File.ReadAllText(@"content\javascript.js"));


}
```

Comment: It's in the documentation I already link you https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Comment: `IsBrowserInitializedChanged` has nothing to do with `Javascript` execution

Comment: The `API Doc` is at http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/R_Project_Documentation.htm

Comment: @amaitland as I asked, I want to know when the chromium is initialized to run the javascript after that. So I guess IsBrowserInitializedChanged is that what I'm looking for.

Comment: If your target is to execute javascript (which is what it appears like to me), then read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript (which I've already link). You cannot execute javascript when the browser has been initialized, it's too soon. The error message I'm guessing you are seeing from your code is somewhat misleading, ignore it and read the link.

Answer (score 0):

I found in the CefSharp code a member that does the job

```
// Summary: Gets a value that indicates whether CefSharp is initialized.
public static bool IsInitialized { get; }
```